# How to refactor ProgramState usage in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, refactoring, state

One of the things that I stumbled upon is that I don't know how to refactor usage of `ProgramState`. Here are some definitions:

```
data ProgramState = ProgramState {
  a :: TypeA,
  b :: TypeB,
  c :: TypeC
}

type SearchFunc = ProgramState -> String -> [Completion]

type MS = ReaderT SearchFunc (StateT ProgramState IO)

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (InputT m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
    state = lift . state

type MS = ReaderT SearchFunc (StateT ProgramState IO)
```

What I do in most functions is:

```
func :: InputT MS ()
func = do
  ProgramState a b c <- get
  -- use a b c and generate newa, newb, newc
  put $ ProgramState newa newb newc
```

There are ~300 similar usages of `ProgramState` throughout the program and it is a real pain when I add another element to `ProgramState` because then I need to change all 300 usages of `ProgramState` in a program. How to refactor my program to avoid this pain of necessity to change similar code in 300 different places?

Comment: One option is lenses and the `HasTypeA env => StateT env a` pattern. This is described in the [RIO readme](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-0.1.15.0#readme) (the "Monads" section) for example.

Comment: `RecordWildCards` would be another option. Or eg. lenses to specify which fields are being modified. There are plenty of ways to avoid explicit construction/deconstruction on all parameters.

Comment: To expand on @ReinHenrichs comment, I like using the [combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#g:5) for `Setter`s (from `lens` or `microlens-mtl`) to set state variables in `MonadState`s.

Answer (score 3):

The base language provides record updates essentially for this reason:

```
func :: InputT MS ()
func = do
    -- -XNamedFieldPuns  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv can simplify this to {a, b, c}
    inState@ProgramState { a = a, b = b, c = c } <- get
    -- etc.
    put inState { a = newA, b = newB, c = newC }
```

`RecordWildCards` also makes the following possible, but I find it less clear:

```
func = do
    ProgramState{..} <- get -- release ALL of the fields
    -- etc.
    put ProgramState { a = newA, b = newB , c = newC, .. }
    -- rebuild with certain specified values and then pass anything not mentioned through
```